# Spatial Locality for 3D array's?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, memory-management, multidimensional-array

why is A[k][i][j] better for spatial locality in a 3D array? ( where i,j,k are row, col, depth) [CMU lecture 55min](https://scs.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Viewer.aspx?id=06dfcd19-1024-49eb-add8-3486a38d1426)

[image: Check image for Question]

Comment: Better than what?????

Comment: sorry the image update failed earlier

Comment: It's been a while, but could you please edit the question, adding the relevant part of the image as *text*? It would make more clear that "where i,j,k are row, col, depth" is a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that example is completely wrong. While rank 0 goes from 0..M-1, that loop is iterating 0..N-1. Unless `M==N`, you'll be reading the wrong element.

The goal is to have your loop iteratively access physically-adjacent locations in memory by manipulating the order of the loops.

Whenever your program reads a value, the CPU requests it from the cache controller. If it's not in cache, that value - **and those near it** - are retrieved from memory and stored in the cache.

If you then read the next element, it should (usually) already be in the cache, so there's no slow round-trip out to the next cache or host RAM.

If your loop is walking all over the place rather than taking advantage of spatial locality, then you run the risk of suffering far more cache misses, which makes things slow.

In short: getting stuff from the cache is fast, getting it from RAM is slow, and ordering your loops so that they touch adjacent locations helps keep the cache happy.

In graphics, we typically do this:

```
int a[M*N*N];

for(int offset=0; offset < M*N*N; ++offset)
{
  //int y = offset / cols;
  //int x = offset % rows;
  sum += a[offset];  
}
```

if you need an element by it's X,Y, just

```
 offset = Y * cols + X;
 int val = a[offset];
```

or for 3D

```
offset = Z*N*N + Y*N + X
```

or

```
offset = Z * rows * cols + Y * cols + X;
```

... and skip all the multidimensional array silliness.

Personally, I'd just do this:

```
int *p = &a[0][0][0]; // could probably just do int* p=a, but for clarity...

//... array gets populated somehow
for(int i=0;i<M*N*N;++i)
{
  sum += p[i];
}
```

... but that assumes the array is a regular square array, not an array of pointers, or an array of an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that OP's question

> why is A[k][i][j] better for spatial locality in a 3D array? ( where i,j,k are row, col, depth)

Comes from a misunderstanding of the exercise given as an example of spatial locality, where the reader is asked to

> **permute the loops** so that the function ... has good spatial locality

and this code is given:

```
int sum_array_3d(int a[M][N][N]) 
{
    int i, j, k, sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
                sum += a[k][i][j];

    return sum;
}
```

My interpretation of this task is that the students are asked to either rewrite the inner statement as `sum += a[i][j][k];` or change the order of the loops:

```
int sum_array_3d(int a[M][N][N]) 
{
    int i, j, k, sum = 0;

    for (k = 0; k < M; k++)            // <-- those are reordered
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
                sum += a[k][i][j];     // <-- this is mantained, verbatim

    return sum;
}
```